# Using compression middleware in express app not working

Tags: express, npm, compression, gzip

So im trying to compress all responses in my express app using this middleware: https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression

The code is really simple:

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

// compress all responses
app.use(compression())

//rest of my code
```

I can run my app locally after this change but nothing is getting compressed. When i push it to heroku where my app is hosted, the app crashes.

Im new to this kind of thing so i might be missing something, but what?

Comment: How have you determined that nothing is being compressed?  When your app crashes on Heroku, what error does it show?

Comment: I checked the response-headers in chrome as ive seem people do, but it doesnt show anything about compression. It jusr says "application error" when trying to connect to the site.